# Cleanup Function running on initial render of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, deployment

```
export default function Input() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function callback(e) {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        inputRef.current.focus();
      }
    }
    console.log("added");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", callback);

    return () => {
      console.log("removed");
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", callback);
    };
  }, []);

  function handleClick() {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to focus</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a simple Input element here. On pressing the Enter key, the input element is focused. The thing I cannot understand is, on the initial render of this component, the console displays both the 'added' and 'removed' message but the cleanup function only executes before the re-render of component or when a component unmounts. So why am I getting the 'removed' message on initial render.

I am only expecting to see the 'added' message on the initial render.

Comment: Does this happen in development only? Are you using [StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#strictmode)? If so, it's the expected behavior of StrictMode in development which reruns the effects twice. You can read more about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect hook, the dependency array is empty ([]), which means the effect runs only once after the initial render. However, the cleanup function returned from the effect is also invoked once immediately before the effect runs for the first time (during the initial render). This is why you see both "added" and "removed" messages.
If you want to see "removed" only when the component unmounts or when the effect dependencies change, you can include inputRef.current in the dependency array like this,

```js
useEffect(() => {
  function callback(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }

  console.log("added");
  document.addEventListener("keydown", callback);

  return () => {
    console.log("removed");
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", callback);
  };
}, [inputRef.current]); // ...include inputRef.current in the dependency array
```